# Solr search with period in phrase is not matching - why?

Tags: solr

I have a record in Solr which represents a company - the company name is in a field called "owner_name" with the value of "something.net".  If I do a Solr query for "owner_name:something" I do not get any results but if I search for "owner_name:something.net" I do.

Here is the fieldType definition this field is using

```xml
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

I don't understand why this is not getting tokenized at "something" and "net".  I would want  "something.net" to return results also, but most people will just search for "something".

What can I do to get searched for both "something" and "something.net" to return this record?

### Update

The word I'm looking for is actually "sawhorse.net" - I was just using "something" to be generic.  I played around more with the field analyzer and I see that that sawhorse.net is getting expanded (see screenshots.)  It seems at the end the stemmer is changing the form, but that happens on index and query so I'm still not sure why it doesn't work.  Here are the screenshots from the field analyzer

[image: sawhorse] [image: sawhorse.net]

Comment: Strange, according to the screen shot you posted, this should generate a hit. As you can see, it is highlighted slightly grey.

Comment: @cheffe - right - that's what I thought. - but I figured it out.  They It is actually stored as SawHorse.net - I didn't realize the H was capital.  see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - my mistake - but maybe someone can learn from this.

The solution is that the name was actually "SawHorse.net" - I didn't realize the "H" is capital.  The word delimiter is breaking it into ['sawhorse.net','saw','horse','net'] - if I didn't have the .net, then the preserveOriginals along with the LowerCaseFilterFactory would have had it match.

I solved it by adding a 

at the end of the index and query sections - the results are shown below.

"sawhorse" - before
[image: searching for "sawhorse" - before change]

"sawhorse" - after
[image: searching for "sawhorse" - after change]

"sawhorse.net" - after
[image: searching for "sawhorse.net" - after change]

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in your  `<analyzer type="index">` vs  `<analyzer type="query">` sections. You have solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory set on indexing but not for queries. What this means is that if a word has been broken up at indexing time (let's say on a period but could also be a hyphen or a number of anything else that it's configured to split words on) if you search on that same word at query time it won't parse it the same way.

Generally speaking in Solr you want to match your indexing filters and tokenizers with you query time filters and tokenizers. There are cases where you don't, but they either are documented in the description of the filter or tokenizer, or you are making adjustment for a very specific use case after you've experimented for awhile.

Details on what solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory is doing can be found here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters